# Integrate Replace in a Private Sub

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How to integrate Replace in this Private Sub?

I need to replace all words "NONE" with "":

```
Private Sub UpdateSKU()

   Dim str As String
   str = Me.Combo216.Column(1) & Space(1) & Me.Combo224.Column(1) & Space(1)
   Me.Text423.Value = str

End Sub
```

I have tried

```
Private Function NONE(a As String)
   
   If InStr(a, "NONE") > 0 Then
      MsgBox "Original: " & a & vbCrLf & "Adjusted: " & Replace(a, "NONE", "")
   End If
End Function
```

But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

A function should return a value...

Your function does not declare a return type, nor does it ever assign a return value.

Try this instead:

```
Private Function NONE(a As String) As String
    NONE = Replace(a, "NONE", "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub UpdateSKU()

   Dim Text As String
   Text = Me.Combo216.Column(1) & Space(1) & Me.Combo224.Column(1) & Space(1)
   Me.Text423.Value = Replace(Text, "NONE", "")

End Sub
```

Also, don't use common function names (Str) for variables, and do rename your controls to something meaningful.